# WPF C# DynamicDataDisplay - Changing the DateTimeAxis Color

Tags: c#, wpf, charts, dynamic-data-display

I'd like to know how could I change the color of the date time axis of my d3 chartplotter.

[image]

The color that I want to change is the brown color and the white background color between the two bars.

If i do that :

It only changes the thing above the first brown bar.

[image]

Is it possible to change the color of these two bars ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Curiously, I've happened to be trying to do the same thing.  It turns out those colours are hard-coded in `MayorDateTimeLabelProvider.cs` (I've noted the lines in comments below).  If you're using the compiled DLL then there is no way to change the values.  Personally, D3 is so immature that I keep my own build of it and make changes to extend it as needed (such as in this case!).

```
public override UIElement[] CreateLabels(ITicksInfo<DateTime> ticksInfo)
{
    object info = ticksInfo.Info;
    var ticks = ticksInfo.Ticks;
    UIElement[] res = new UIElement[ticks.Length - 1];
    int labelsNum = 3;

    if (info is DifferenceIn)
    {
        DifferenceIn diff = (DifferenceIn)info;
        DateFormat = GetDateFormat(diff);
    }
    else if (info is MayorLabelsInfo)
    {
        MayorLabelsInfo mInfo = (MayorLabelsInfo)info;
        DifferenceIn diff = (DifferenceIn)mInfo.Info;
        DateFormat = GetDateFormat(diff);
        labelsNum = mInfo.MayorLabelsCount + 1;

        //DebugVerify.Is(labelsNum < 100);
    }

    DebugVerify.Is(ticks.Length < 10);

    LabelTickInfo<DateTime> tickInfo = new LabelTickInfo<DateTime>();
    for (int i = 0; i < ticks.Length - 1; i++)
    {
        tickInfo.Info = info;
        tickInfo.Tick = ticks[i];

        string tickText = GetString(tickInfo);

        Grid grid = new Grid
        {
            Background = Brushes.Beige // **** HARD CODED HERE
        };
        Rectangle rect = new Rectangle
        {
            Stroke = Brushes.Peru,     // **** AND HERE
            StrokeThickness = 2
        };
        Grid.SetColumn(rect, 0);
        Grid.SetColumnSpan(rect, labelsNum);

        for (int j = 0; j < labelsNum; j++)
        {
            grid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition());
        }

        grid.Children.Add(rect);

        for (int j = 0; j < labelsNum; j++)
        {
            var tb = new TextBlock
            {
                Text = tickText,
                HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center,
                Margin = new Thickness(0, 3, 0, 3)
            };
            Grid.SetColumn(tb, j);
            grid.Children.Add(tb);
        }

        ApplyCustomView(tickInfo, grid);

        res[i] = grid;
    }

    return res;
}
```

Comment: I’m also doing the same thing (using my own custom version of D3) and your proposed solution worked perfectly. Thank you.